# What happens if no final subtraction is done in Montgomery multiplication?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, montgomery-multiplication

I'm doing Montgomery arithmetic modulo $N = 2^{255}-19$ for the Curve25519, picking $R = 2^{256}$ for Montgomery.

After multiplying two numbers $0 \leq A,B < N$ in the Montgomery representation using `MonMul`, I would normally obtain the result $0 \leq C < N$ also in the Montgomery representation.

However, if I forget the conditional subtraction in `MonMul` I obtain some $0 \leq C^{\prime} < 2N$. In other words, I basically ended up in a different representation which is not unique anymore.

I could live with that and do all the additions/subtractions modulo $2^{256}-38$ instead afterwards. That means I basically postponed the conditional subtraction until the end of my whole computation.

But my question is what happens if I have to do `MonMul` again somewhere during my computation? It would mean that one (or both) of the input numbers for `MonMul` could be in fact between $N$ and $2N$.

Do I have to make the conditional subtraction before doing the `MonMul` again (to put my numbers back in the right representation)? Or can I still postpone it until the end? I realized that not doing the subtraction before any repeated multiplication didn't spoil the computation so far. Does it really hold universally for my $N$?

Comment: Stupid question: why are you using Montgomery Multiplication for $2^{255}-19$ in the first place?  The reason we do Montgomery Multiplication is to make the modulo operation easier; however with $N=2^{255}-19$, it's already awfully easy, as $a \cdot 2^{255} + b \equiv a \cdot 19 + b \pmod{2^{255}-19}$

Comment: I expected that question :) Because Montgomery multiplication saves me some code memory which I am optimizing for. Doing A*B and then doing the full reduction using what you just said requires far more code than for example CIOS Montgomery multiplication.

Comment: @NumberFour, as Poncho pointed out, the reduction process is obvious for this modulus format. Observe that $A \star B \; mod \; N \simeq \; A \star \; B \; - \; [High(A\star  \;B)]\star N$.
And this can also be optimised, without going to Montgomery arithmetic which necessitate additionnal pre and post process.

Comment: I was already experimenting with all that. I am doing a specific implementation for a device with very restricted instruction set. For some reasons, I cannot optimize for speed but for code size and memory consumed. Montgomery comes out with least code size and memory requirements. Also the pre- and post- processing comes for free (in terms of extra memory) since `MonPro` could be used for this purpose as well.

Comment: I don't expect your algorithm to work without exceptions.
You mentioned result is below $2N$, so try to square, through montgomery multiplication, $2N-1$ and see if the result is above $2N$. Note, don't convert anything into/from montgomery, just compute `MonMul(2N-1,2N-1)`.

Comment: @NumberFour, I understand your question now. If correctly implemented, it could happen that the result of MonMul gives a result C located between N and 2.N, when the radix R is relativelly prime with N. 
Then $i.R^{-1}$ is a complete residue system which is homomorphic to the regular $\mathbb{Z}_N$.
Then the last substraction can be postponed to the final step.

Comment: Following Ruggero's comment I actually I tried to do a simple estimate: in `MonMul` you compute $t = a\cdot b$ and the  $u = (t + (t\cdot n^{\prime} \mod R)\cdot N)\cdot R^{-1}$ and by knowing the inputs $a$ and $b$ were in proper Montgomery representation, you can estimate $u < 2N$. However, in my case both inputs could be equal $2N-1$ in the worst case. By plugging it in, I get the $2N < u < 3N$, which means two final subtractions might be needed. Is it correct?

Comment: No. Because it might also happen that after that you perform another multiplication with inputs $2N<u<3N$ and maybe you get an output $3N<u<4N$.
I don't think a general answer exists because you are not doing MonMul only. You are doing also modular addition and subtraction (I guess). 
Peraphs a definitive answer could be provided only if you decribe in detail the implementation.

Comment: @Ruggero Of course. I was just considering 2 multiplications in a row, but as with the ladder step with XZ coordinates, there are more multiplications and also additions/subtractions. But anyway, I don't really see a way to avoid the final subtraction other than increasing $R$. No doing the subtraction doesn't even make the code size smaller (because I would need the conditional subtraction code later anyway), so I will do the final subtraction properly.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 2 in [[Dussé et al. 1991]](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-46877-3_21) states that, if we skip the final subtraction, then, for $N < R / 4$ and $0 \leq A, B < 2 N$, we have $0 \leq C = \text{MonMul}(A B) < 2 N$, while keeping $C \equiv A B R^{-1} \pmod N$. I think the condition $N < R / 4$ inherently holds in your case e.g. you are using larger $R$ value acutually.